# Tags for key bindings

Tags: discussion, tags

How should we tag questions about key bindings?

Right now we have a [keymap](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keymap) tag. I'm wondering if we should use that for all questions of the form “how do I bind a key (or mouse event?) to this action”, or if we should use [keymap](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keymap) for questions about manipulating keymaps as Lisp objects and [key-bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/key-bindings) (like the [manual chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings)) for the general concept of binding a key (or key sequence or other input events) to an action.

Comment: I like your suggestion, but I'm worried the keymap tag might be highly missused.

Answer (score 3):

I think for the sake of simplicity we should try to keep only one tag (and probably aliases) for those two aspects.

I might be wrong, but I would expect questions specifically about keymaps to be mostly about what keymaps are active at any given time and in what order they are searched. Which would indirectly be a question about where to define a keybinding, and how to make sure it's visible.

Comment: If only one is kept, `key-bindings` is probably the one to keep. That is the tag used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Drew If we decide that [tag:keymap] and [tag:key-bindings] should mean the same thing, we can have both and declare them to be synonyms.